# How to add multiple buttons in eclipse

Tags: java, android, button, android-manifest

I know how to add a single button to the XML, Java, and Manifest but I don't know how to add multiple buttons. Can you help me with the code for the Java file and the Manifest.

Comment: umm.. add the button to *manifest*? just drop them to your activity layout from the pane with the controls...

Comment: Go through the starter tutorials for Android.  They show how to add multiple components to a screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to add multiple buttons in your java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button button1, button2, button3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //figure out which button was pressed:
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            //do button1 actions
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            //do button2 actions
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            //do button3 actions
            break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's with 'every-other-blank-line'?  They don't assist a reader to understand the source, and do not make it run faster.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TestActivity1 extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   Button  button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button  button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

   }
}
```